# Show that $2$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$, using an element $\alpha$ obtained from an extension field as a root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

This problem asks me to show that $2$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $8$ through a number of steps, the first step is the following problem:

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $\alpha$ be the root of $x^4 + 1$ in some extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, let $y= \alpha + \alpha^{-1}$, show that $y^2 = 2$.

**EDIT:**
Someone has posted an answer proving the above part of the problem, but I asked them for help solving the remaining parts of the problem. To provide context for the answer they provided, here is the full problem (and my efforts to solve it):

The main problem is to prove that $x^2 = 2$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $8$. This should be done through a series of steps; part a) is stated above, and part b) and c) are as follows:

b): Show that $y^p = \alpha^p + \alpha^{-p}$

c): Show that $y \in \mathbb{F}_p$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $8$.  One may use that a non zero element $a$ in an extension of $\mathbb{F_p}$ lies in $\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $a^{p-1} = 1$

I have proven b), and it turned out to be useful in c) when assuming that $p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $8$ to prove one implication. I also proved that if $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ then $a^{p-1} = 1$ (by considering the multiplicative group and generating a subgroup whose order divide $p-1$, the usual trick.

What I dont understand is the two other implications, namely $a^{p-1} = 1 \implies a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and the other part in c), namely $y \in \mathbb{F}_p \implies p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $8$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is not necessarily in $\mathbb{F}_p$ all you know is that $\alpha$ is in some field of characteristic $p$. So you cannot conclude that $\alpha^{p-1} = 1$. However, you do know that $\alpha^4+1=0$ which is enough to prove what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck How come the extension field has characteristic $p$?

Comment: Because extending a field preserves the characteristic. Adding $1+1+...+1$ for a total of $p$ times is still $0$.

Comment: More importantly: The whole "extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$" is a bit of a red hering. This is provable without referring to $p$ in any way.

Comment: I noticed that the title, and the first line of your post didn't reflect the statement of your full problem you made after the edit. I have corrected this with an edit (and added a new tag). When the edit is approved, please check that I have phrased things correctly according to the updated problem statement, and I have not messed anything up. If you disagee with the changes, you can always rollback my edit.

Comment: An alternate way of proving this: observe that $(1+i)^p \equiv 1 + i^p \pmod{p}$ but also $(1+i)^p = 2^{(p-1)/2} i^{(p-1)/2} (1+i)$ in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which allows you to compute what $2^{(p-1)/2}$ is congruent to modulo $p$ in the integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) is actually quite simple; all you need is the algebraic properties of $\alpha$.

We know that $\alpha^4+1=0$, so dividing by $\alpha$ tells us that $\alpha^3+\alpha^{-1}=0$, thus $\alpha^{-1}=-\alpha^3$. We therefore have that
\begin{equation}
y=(\alpha+\alpha^{-1})^2=2+\alpha^2+\alpha^{-2}=2+\alpha^2+\alpha^6=2+\alpha^2(\alpha^4+1)=2
\end{equation}
as desired.

To solve (b), by the freshman's dream, $y^p=\alpha^p+\alpha^{-p}$.

Now, we may approach part (c) by cases:

If $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod 8$, then
\begin{equation}
y^p=\alpha^p+\alpha^{-p}=\alpha^{8n\pm 1}+\alpha^{-8n\mp 1}=(\alpha^8)^n\alpha^{\pm 1}+(\alpha^8)^{-n}\alpha^{\mp 1}=\alpha^{\pm 1}+\alpha^{\mp 1}=y
\end{equation}
(since $\alpha^8=1$) which means that $y$ is a root of $x^p-x$, and thus it must be a member of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Otherwise, if $p\not\equiv\pm 1\pmod 8$, then we have that $p\equiv \pm 3\pmod 8$, so
\begin{equation}
y^p=\alpha^p+\alpha^{-p}=\alpha^{8n\pm 3}+\alpha^{-8n\mp 3}=(\alpha^8)^n\alpha^{\pm 3}+(\alpha^8)^{-n}\alpha^{\mp 3}=
\alpha^{\pm 3}+\alpha^{\mp 3}=
\alpha^{ 3}+\alpha^{-3}=\alpha^{4}(\alpha^{-1}+\alpha^{-7})=-(\alpha^{-1}+\alpha)=-y
\end{equation}
(since $\alpha^4=-1$ and $\alpha^8=1$) In other words, $y$ is not a root of $x^p-x$, so it must not be a member of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Therefore, we have shown that $y\in\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $p\equiv\pm 1\pmod 8$.

To conclude, since the polynomial $x^2=2$ can only have two roots in any extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $y,-y$ are precisely those two roots, then $x^2=2$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod 8$.

## Addendum:

Why is it true that $y\in\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $y$ is a root of $x^p-x$?

To see this, note that $x^p-x$ is a degree $p$ polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so it must have at most $p$ roots in any extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Also, note that by Fermat's little theorem, every one of the $p$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a root of $x^p-x$. This means that the roots of $x^p-x$ in an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ are precisely the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I have edited the question, I will remove my comments under this post to make it more understandable for others.

Comment: Hmm. How do you know that $y$ must be a member of $\mathbb{F}_p$ just because it is a root? I used the last part of c) here, namely since $y^{p-1}  = 1$ we have $y \in \mathbb{F}_p$, however I couldnt come up with a proof for this. 

Actually this shows one of the implications butI am not following how you conclude $y \in \mathbb{F}_p \implies p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $8$ at all here, could you please clarify the idea of the other case..?

Comment: @LocationMap2 I have clarified. In particular, it is sufficient to show that if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod 8$, then $y\in\mathbb{F}_p$, and if $p\not\equiv \pm 1\pmod 8$, then $y\not\in\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @LocationMap2 I've also edited your question to more clearly describe exactly how and why you expanded it (and added a relevant tag). When the changes are accepted, hopefully you're ok with them. If not, feel free to rollback the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat similar to C-RAM's solution, but simpler.

We have been given that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4 + 1$

Thus $\alpha^4 +1 =0$

Clearly, $\alpha \not = 0$

divide by $\alpha ^2$

we get $\alpha^2 + \alpha^{-2} = 0$

I hope you can take it from here.